# Basic ag-grid table keeps automatically increasing height/top infinitely

Tags: css, reactjs, ag-grid

I have a barebone React component  that uses AG-Grid to render out a table. But I'm running into this issue where the height/top automatically keeps increasing, without any input from me.

```
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css";

render () {
    const colDef = [{
        headerName: "Make", field: "make",
        }, {
        headerName: "Model", field: "model",
        }, {
        headerName: "Price", field: "price",
        }];

    const dataRows = [{
        make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000,
        }, {
        make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000,
        }, {
        make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000,
        }];

    return (
         <div className={`ag-theme-material`}>
            <AgGridReact
                columnDefs={colDef}
                rowData={dataRows}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I inspected the elements that changes. It looks like `Top` keeps increasing automatically for this div:

```
<div class="ag-floating-bottom" role="presentation" style="height: 0px; top: 422px;">
```

and `Height` for this, and I have no idea why:

```
<div class="ag-body ag-row-no-animation" role="presentation" style="height: 516px; top: 56px;">
```

Note that I tried the other build in themes for ag-grid and ran into the same issue.

Comment: Can u reproduce this issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily?

Comment: I've created it here but for some reason it's not showing up https://codesandbox.io/s/8zv4z0q79

Comment: @blankface : Where you able to find any solution for this? I am running into same issue. for me it is working fine in IE but chrome however is acting funky.